# Access and Modify Nested Object based on Array of Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, material-ui

I'm working on a recursive form based on a nested object, using React and MUI, and I'm to keeping track of the previous keys during the recursion.

At some point, as the user changes the form, I need to change the corresponding nested, state object.

So, I would need, in order to access the value in the form, some way of doing something similar to this:

```js
const keyList = [k1, k2, ..., kn]

form[k1][k2]...[kn]
```

And, in the same vein, in order to set the value:

```js
<TextField
  onChange={(e) => {
    const newForm = { ...form }

    newForm[k1][k2]...[kn] = newValue

    setForm(newForm)
  }}
/>
```

Is there a way of dealing with this? If so, how?

Comment: something similar to lodash get and set https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get  https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set

Comment: :O I didn't know Lodash had something like that!

Comment: if you are using lodash already better go for it. its well tested

Comment: [This other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912542/4756173) really helped and did work for the most part, but I think I'm ditching it in favor of Lodash, all the more because they did some TypeScript sorcery that does in the work type-wise as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [often use](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20getPath&searchOn=3) functions [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20setPath&searchOn=3):

```js
const getPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? o : getPath (ps) (o && o[p])

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )
```

Given `const keyList = [k1, k2, ..., kn]`, with these functions

```js
form[k1][k2]...[kn]
```

could be written

```js
getPath (keyList) (form)
```

and

```js
const newForm = { ...form }

newForm[k1][k2]...[kn] = newValue

setForm(newForm)
```

could be written

```js
setForm (setPath (keyList) (newValue) (form))
```

### Edit

An edit added this content:

> As mentioned by @cmgchess, you could also use Lodash's [`get`](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get) and [`set`](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set).

This is true, but there might be a concern about the API (since lodash's version starts with `"path.to.node"` rather than `["path", "to", "node"]` as does the proposed alternative.  Worse, from my perspective, is that `set` mutates its input.  I'm not sure how that will work with your React environment, but I personally try to avoid that as much as possible.  `setPath` above does not mutate the input, but avoids a complete deep clone by structurally sharing what it can of the input.